# Does Stack Overflow provide public Python APIs for querying?

Tags: support, api

I'm interested in writing an application on top of Stack Overflow. For example: Get the answers to the questions identified by a set of ids, get the questions that are related to the questions identified by a set of ids etc.

Does Stack Overflow provide some sort of Python API for the public?

Comment: SE has an API... see https://api.stackexchange.com/. I'd be surprised if someone hadn't written a Python library wrapper around it so maybe have a look around github/bitbucket/pypi and you might find something.

Comment: @JonClements in what programming language HTTP APIs mentioned in api.stackexchange.com are written?

Comment: IIRC all of the code for the sites is .NET based. Fairly sure there's more detailed explanations of what tech is used and what servers are used etc etc... somewhere on here... might be worth having a search for :)

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I found a python wrapper https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange. I guess this will work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow doesn't provide language-specific implementations, it only offers the API as it is: a collection of endpoints for HTTP calls. Luckily, we have volunteers who write libraries and post them on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com), the dedicated Stack Exchange for API support. [Here](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20%5blibrary%5d%20is%3aq) is a list of the most popular Python libraries; it includes Py-StackExchange which you've already found.

Support for those libraries is usually available by posting an *answer* to the 'question' announcing the library; in that respect, Stack Apps works a little counter-intuitively when compared to most Stack Exchange sites (though Meta and its announcements follow the same pattern). In this particular case, you can also [drop an email to the maintainer](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange#next-steps).